# How to get data from another file in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.

I retrieved data from url in Posts.js.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Posts = () => {
   const[data, setData] = useState([]);
   useEffect(() => {
       axios.get('myURL')
       .then(response => {
           setData({data: response.data});
       })
       .catch(error => {
           console.log(error);
       })
     }, []);
}
export default Posts;
```

In `data`, I see json objects.

I would like to use this `data` to App.js.

How can I use `data` from this file to my App.js?

Comment: Type one google , react how to create model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass a function in App.js as a prop to `Posts` component and trigger that function whenever you receive `data`.

```
      <Posts onReceivingData = {onReceivingData}>
```